# Angular 2 - http - Observable - start/stop/running states

Tags: angular, observable

I've a form which fetches data with an http observable. While loading the data and waiting for the response I want to disable the submit button.

Currently I've implemented status code on each component/form to set the status to running before the subscribe method is called and disable the running flag if the response is there.

The problem is that I have to implement this check on each component/form. I'd like to wrap the observable with a model which sets the status information before the request is made.

What is the best aproach? I didn't find a solution to add a function before the request is made. The Observable has no before functionality. I've also tried to concat two Observables. The first one is only used to indicate that the second Observable is starting.

Is there a simple way to listen to the start of an observable in an abstract way. I would like to wrap the http service to hold the (start/stop/running/...) states...

**Edit 1:**

Here is some pseudo code of what im currently doing. I've added this state holder on every observable which is triggered by a button. I whant to remove this duplicated code.

```
this.mystateHolder.start(); // sets running;error,success to false
this.myservice.updateSomething(mydata).subscibe(
   ok => mysateHolder.stop(false) // sets success to true and running to false
   error => mystateHOlder.stop(true, error) // sets error to true and running to false
)
<button [disabeld]="mystateHolder.isRunning()"></button>
<span *ngIf="mystateHolder.hasErrors()">mystateHolder.getErrorMessage()</span>
```

Target pseudo code (maybe):

```
const state = this.myservice.updateSomething(mydata).state()
state.subscribe();
console.log(state.hasErrors())
console.log(state.isRunning())
console.log(state.success())
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make the calls you need before you go to the desired state. This can be done within the router you use with the resolve parameter.
(https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve if you use angular router, ui-router provides this too).
The other thing I can think of is to just check if the data is available in the button's tag with [disable] property like that:

```
<button [disable]="data === null">Submit</button>
```

or some other check with suits your problem.

Comment: I've updated my example (Edit 1). If I check for the data then its also another state check. What if no data is returned? I have to do it again and again on every observable for all the specific usecases but its everytime the same...